# UiPath Open Browser Activity

Tags: uipath, uipath-activity, uipath-api

What packages must be installed to use the Open Browser activity on UiPath? I cannot seem to find it and I installed the WebApi package. I onl see the "Use application/browser" activity.

After installing the webapi package I expected to find it the open browser activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the "Use application/browser" Activity comes pre-installed in UIPATH. Go to activities and search Use Application/Browser.

Answer (score 1):

The "Use Application/Browser" activity is a part of the "UiAutomation" package and it should come preinstalled with UiPath.

However, if you cannot find it for some reason then make sure the package is correctly installed:

1. In the "Activities" panel, click on the "Manage Packages" option.
2. In the "Manage Packages" window, go to the "All Packages" tab.
3. Search for the "UiAutomation" package.
4. If it's not installed, click the "Install" button to install it. If it's installed but you can't find the "Open Browser" activity, you might need to update it to the latest version.

Once installed or updated, you should be able to find that activity in the activities panel.